# How keep the layout of an HTML textarea when past in SAS macro variable?

Tags: html, sas, textarea, sas-macro

I create a custom input form for a SAS Stored Process which produce a report and send it in a mail.

In a first screen, a form is display and I have a text area where user will be able to write some texts and this text will be display above the report. Code of text area is like this :

```
<textarea col=10 row=10 name='textarea'> </textarea>
```

So for example if my user want to writte :

> ```
> -Hello this is my first line.
> -And my second line without point for example
> - and a third.
> ```

But after processing, in the text enter by user and pass in the macro variable `&textarea` in SAS, blanck are compress and not considered (that is Normal in SAS).
 So text display in report when the form is submit is not as wish, it is just one line.

> ```
> -Hello this is my first line. -And my second line without point for example - and a third.
> ```

Moreover, my user can reactualize the form to see the result before sending, and in the text area the content of the macro-variable is used. So same problem.

So how overpass the SAS behavior ?

I though that html encode/decode function would  be a solution but not. I also tought that a macro program to recreate many macro-variables (one per sentences) would be a solution, but it is difficult to ensure what would be used as delimiter of sentence by user. So I gave up this idea.

If someone has an idea or a solution, i will be very grateful.

Comment: Explain your 'processing'.  The text area entry made available via a macro of the same name should have \r\n embedded.

Comment: How are you generating the output for review?  Did you wrap the output of the value read inside of `<pre>` tag so that system displaying the result know not to reflow the lines?

Answer (score 0):

You should add some `<br />` to your code like :

```
<textarea col=10 row=10 name='textarea'>   <br /></textarea>
```

Not sure of what am i saying but try it out then tell me pls !

Answer (score 0):

The SAS Stored Process Web Application for running stored processes **will** maintain cr/lf as entered in a `textarea`

Consider this stored process, stored in the SAS server metadata folder `Demo/TextArea`, that captures a Comment in a text area:

```
data _null_;
  name = "&Comment";
  do i = 1 to length(name); * log each character and its ascii code;
    c = substr(name,i,1);
    b = rank(c);
    putlog i= c= b=;
  end;
run;

proc stream outfile=_webout; BEGIN
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Area test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=post>
Name: <input name=Name type="text" length=20><br />
Comment:<br />
<textarea name=Comment rows=10 cols=60></textarea><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
;;;;
```

When invoked from a browser, with `_debug=log` as

```
http://mysasserver:mysasserverport/SASStoredProcess/do?_Program=/Demo/TextArea&_debug=log
```

and the Comment text area filled in with

```
This
is
my comment
```

and submitted, the SAS log shown in the page will show cr/lf, (13/10), were sent from the text area newlines (per browser HTML spec):

```
…
 COMMENT=This
is
my comment
…
i=1 c=T b=84
i=2 c=h b=104
i=3 c=i b=105
i=4 c=s b=115
i=5 c=
 b=13
i=6 c=
 b=10
i=7 c=i b=105
i=8 c=s b=115
i=9 c=
 b=13
i=10 c=
 b=10
i=11 c=m b=109
i=12 c=y b=121
i=13 c=  b=32
i=14 c=c b=99
i=15 c=o b=111
i=16 c=m b=109
i=17 c=m b=109
i=18 c=e b=101
i=19 c=n b=110
i=20 c=t b=116
```

Comment: ok I will try to use the value of 'b' as clue to insert <br> in a new macro variable my report.
But another question. How Redisplay this text in the textarea ? 
More precisely, my stored process is chaining and can be submit and point to itself. And if the textarea was filled, text entry previsouly will be display again in the text area (like prepopulate prompt). But same problem, and <br> is not undestand by this input. So how keep the layout ?

Comment: You will have to show the code you use to create the html `<form>`. In particular how the `<textarea>` part.